# Pointer to pointer to struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm making stack implementation in C using pointers and struct. Push and crateStack functions work well (both of them create new element in memory). Anyway, pop function doesnt work and I dont know why, here is code of that function:

```
int pop(element **lastStackEl)
{
  int poppedValue = *lastStackEl->value;
  element *temp = *lastStackEl->prev;
  free(*lastStackEl);
  *lastStackEl=temp;
  return poppedValue;
}
```

And here is my struct:

```
typedef struct Element {
  int value;
  struct Element *prev;
} element;
```

The compiler's giving error in first and second line of pop function:

```
error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
int poppedValue = *lastStackEl->value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the indirection (dereference) operator (`*`) comes later than member access operator (`->`). So, without an explicit parenthesis, your statement behaves like

```
int poppedValue = *(lastStackEl->value);
```

Now, `lastStackEl` being a pointer to pointer to `element` it cannot be used as the LHS of member access operator. That is what the error message is all about.

You need to derefence `lastStackEl` first (to get a `element*` type), and then, you can use the `->` to access the member `value`. You should write

```
int poppedValue = (*lastStackEl)->value;
```